Ctkinter GUI help (python)
I'm creating an app the calculates the monthly subscription and registration fee for patients the code works fine but I suck at GUIs (hence this project). I'm having a few issues but the main one occurs when I try to register more than one patient at once. If I do so, the entries for patient age 2 stacks on top of the plan length for patient 2.
from customtkinter import *

class Patient:
    def __init__(self, patient_num):
        self.patient_num = patient_num
        self.age = 0  # Initialize age to a default value
        self.plan_length = None
        self.prepayment_option = None
        self.total_cost = None


class PatientRegistrationApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Patient Registration App")
        self.master.geometry("750x500")

        self.patients = []
        self.monthly_fee_child = 75
        self.monthly_fee_adult = 100

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.num_label = CTkLabel(self.master, text="How many registrations would you like to make?")
        self.num_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.num_entry = CTkEntry(self.master)
        self.num_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.collect_button = CTkButton(self.master, text="Collect Registrations", command=self.collect_registrations)
        self.collect_button.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)


    def collect_registrations(self):
        num_of_registrations = int(self.num_entry.get())

        for i in range(num_of_registrations):
            self.create_patient(i + 1)
        
        # Disable the collect button after registrations are collected
        self.collect_button.destroy()

    def create_patient(self, patient_num):
        patient = Patient(patient_num)
        self.patients.append(patient)
        self.create_patient_data_widgets(patient)

    def create_patient_data_widgets(self, patient):
        row_start = patient.patient_num

        age_label = CTkLabel(self.master, text=f'Patient {patient.patient_num} Age:')
        age_label.grid(row=row_start, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        age_entry = CTkEntry(self.master)
        age_entry.grid(row=row_start, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        patient.age_entry = age_entry

        plan_length_label = CTkLabel(self.master, text=f'How many months would patient {patient.patient_num} be on the plan?')
        plan_length_label.grid(row=row_start + 1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        plan_length_entry = CTkEntry(self.master)
        plan_length_entry.grid(row=row_start + 1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        patient.plan_length_entry = plan_length_entry

        prepayment_label = CTkLabel(self.master, text=f'Does patient {patient.patient_num} want to make a prepayment? (yes/no):')
        prepayment_label.grid(row=row_start + 2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

        prepayment_entry = CTkEntry(self.master)
        prepayment_entry.grid(row=row_start + 2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
        patient.prepayment_entry = prepayment_entry

        process_button = CTkButton(self.master, text="Process Data", command=lambda: self.process_patient_data(patient))
        process_button.grid(row=row_start + 3, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

    def process_patient_data(self, patient):
        age = int(patient.age_entry.get())
        plan_length = int(patient.plan_length_entry.get())
        prepayment_option = patient.prepayment_entry.get().lower()

        if sum(age >= 22 for age in [p.age for p in self.patients]) > 1:
            self.monthly_fee_adult = 90
        else:
            self.monthly_fee_adult = 100

        total_cost = plan_length * (self.monthly_fee_adult if age >= 22 else self.monthly_fee_child)

        if prepayment_option == 'yes':
            if plan_length == 6:
                total_cost *= 0.95
            elif plan_length == 12:
                total_cost *= 0.9

        patient.age = age
        patient.plan_length = plan_length
        patient.prepayment_option = prepayment_option
        patient.total_cost = total_cost

        self.calculate_monthly_payment(patient)
        self.display_totals(patient)
        self.determine_registration_fee()

    def calculate_monthly_payment(self, patient):
        monthly_payment = patient.total_cost / patient.plan_length
        print(f'Patient {patient.patient_num} Monthly Payment: {monthly_payment:.2f}')

    def display_totals(self, patient):
        print(f'Patient {patient.patient_num} Plan total is {patient.total_cost}')

    def determine_registration_fee(self):
        join_existing_plan = input('Is this Patient Joining an existing Plan? (yes/no)').lower()
        registration_fee = 50 if join_existing_plan == 'yes' else 150
        print(f"Registration fee is {registration_fee}")

root = CTk()
app = PatientRegistrationApp(root)
root.mainloop()

I can keep trying but I'm just burned out, been doing this the past 8 hours. Any help is welcome, mainly just food for thought.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
